# Paper Elements Dart installation

Tags: ios8, dart, paper-elements

I would like to use this: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/paper_elements

I followed these steps for installation:

1. Adding `paper_elements: "^0.7.1+1"` in pubspec.yaml dependencies
2. Importing the desired element into a dummy component template, like so: `<link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_button.html">`
3. Adding `import 'package:paper_elements/paper_button.dart';` into the dummy component
4. Using element like this into component template: `<paper-button raised="" role="button">button</paper-button>`

Compile dummy app with Phonegap. Everything is fine on Android. But the paper button is not rendered in iOS 8. I can only see the `button` text.

Any ideas if paper-elements have issues on iOS 8 or did anyone successfully tested dart paper-elements on iOS 8?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a workaround I found recently. It doesn't mention iOS8 but I guess it's worth a try.

https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/issues/538#issuecomment-141135722

> It appears that problem is in outdated web_components, i got it all working on iOS 9 and OSX 10.11 by overriding web_components in my yams file by adding:

```yml
dependency_overrides:
web_components: "^0.12.0+3"
```